# Analog Multiplexing

Tags: diodes, analog, esp8266, nodemcu

I have NodeMCU which has only one analog input, and I have two analog devices, which I do not need to communicate with at the same time, so I decided to multiplex them! but since I did not have a multiplexer I decided to make my own :)

So I built the circuit depicted below : 
[image]

However, when I print the value being read on A0 I get the weird plot below, which shows the values coming from the diode bouncing between the potentiometer actual value and zero.

**The diode I am using is UF4007MIC ( because this is the only one I have now )**

[image: Serial Plotter Output]

My Question is: Why is this happening ? is it possible to avoid it?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing more about the NodeMCU and what it's driving onto GPIO5 and GPIO4. But I'd imagined you'd be connecting a pot's across to GPIO4 and GND, another across GPIO5 and GND, then each wiper through the diode A-K into A0.

Comment: If you're turning GPIO4 on for a while then turning it off again and turning GPIO5 on for a while then turning it off again, and repeating, then that's the sort of waveform I'd expect to see at A0. This isn't really a multiplexer though, and the diode forward voltage is going to muck up your measurements.

Comment: @Finbarr Atually this is the plot I get while only one of the GPIOs is on and the other is off !and true this is not multiplexing but I was hoping to solve the problem by doing this .. but I got this weird stuff ! :\

Comment: @TonyM Yes true ! and then the GPIOs are used to switch which POT is being read by activating the corresponding GPIO

Comment: You're doing something strange somewhere. Try putting a constant DC voltage into A0 and plotting what you get.

Comment: @Finbarr of course it is something strange :) you can see the circuit diagram .. that's exactly what I have

Comment: For connection to an ADC I would worry that the diodes have a voltage drop high enough to mess with accuracy. Wouldn't transistors in pass-gate configuration be better here?

Comment: I am not really sure about that... But because of the voltage drop i do calibration for the sensors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You currently have an odd wiring of the pots' you're trying to read. But your diode ORing results in two diodes driving into a high-impedance input. You haven't posted any control or timing information about how you're driving GPIO4 and GPIO5 or for how long, so I can't be definitive. But it does seem that the capacitance of the high-impedance A0 input is charged up by the diodes when you drive GPIO4/GPIO5 logic high, then that capacitance is discharged by the A0 input leakage current and the diode's reverse leakage current when you drive GPIO4/GPIO5 logic low or tri-state. That would result in the waveform you're seeing. Whether that's it or not, all these defects need to be removed from the circuit.

Try rewiring your circuit to produce the below. I've shown 1N4148 signal diodes but you can use your UF4007 rectifier diodes if you have to.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwHY3b.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The software routine should be something like:

```
  Drive GPIO4 logic high.
  Drive GPIO5 logic low.
  Wait for x us settling time.
  Read ADC to get R1 measurement.

  Drive GPIO4 logic low.
  Drive GPIO5 logic high.
  Wait for x us settling time.
  Read ADC to get R2 measurement.
```

The readings will have an error in them caused by the inaccurate diode drop. Your system will need to take account of this and tolerate the error, if it can.

The required settling time is because the selected pot's resistance will have to charge the A0 input capacitance and any stray capacitance in your wires etc. If you have the capability to plot graphs of the A0 input voltage, which you appear to have from your question, then you can measure it over, say, 5 ms and determine the required settling time. Add a generous margin to the value you find, say 20 %, to allow for variations in the circuit capacitance and component tolerances.

R3 is there so that D1 and D2 are passing current. Otherwise they may be driving a high-impedance IC input pin. The lower the R3 value, the higher the diode current and the more stable the diode drop. (That's a consideration only at these very low currents.) The higher the R3 value, the smaller the error it introduces into the R1 or R2 potential divider output voltage. If you can, change R1 and R2 to, say, 1 K and R3 to, say, 22 K.

Comment: Thank you very much... I actually tried this yesterday with a bit lower resistor (30K) and it seems like your answer is totally correct. But I still don't understand why the voltage on the diode's output is varying this way? if you can please elaborate on this!

Comment: Done - see comment above